# How can I stop the first option of my context menus from being selected immediately after opening the context menu?

Tags: unity, context-menu

Whenever I open a context menu, the first option of the context menu gets selected immediately. The following video illustrates this:

- https://vid.me/LF5S

Obviously this makes the context menu unusable. How can I fix this?

---

EDIT: Following [a request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677156/how-can-i-stop-the-first-option-of-my-context-menus-from-being-selected-immediat#comment988171_677156) by @kos, I used `mev` to record mouse click events:

- left click: `_(#_(`
- right click: `"_(#_(`

Comment: Install `gpm` (`sudo apt-get install gpm`) and run `mev`; left-click on the terminal window once, hit Ctrl+C and right-click the terminal window once, then please add the output to your question (the only way to stop that is closing the terminal window).

Comment: Hi @kos. Thank you for your comment. I have recorded the representations of the mouse clicks and added them to the question as requested. I have not used this program before, but if I understand the output, I think it indicated that the coördinates of the pointer don't change depending on the click button.

Comment: Well sorry, I'm not an expert, but from the test at least the hardware problem is ruled out. It should be a configuration problem. Unfortunately I have no idea about what that could be.

Comment: @kos Thank you very much for your thoughts and assistance on it. :)